# Using execvp() to Call Linux ps Command

Tags: c, linux, exec, ps

I'm working in C and trying to use `execvp()` to launch the following linux command:

```
ps -o pid,ppid,time --pid 30008
```

I've got the following code right now:

```
char command2[1024];
snprintf(command2, sizeof(command2), "--pid %i", processId);
char *const parmList[] = {"-o pid,ppid,time", command2, NULL};
execvp("/bin/ps", parmList);
```

However, it is not working properly because when I run it, the appropriate columns are not displayed (PID, PPID, and TIME). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to the command list of `execvp()`, which will be `argv[0]`, should be the filename of the executable.  So, `char *const parmList[] = {"ps", "-o pid,ppid,time", command2, NULL};`